# How to remove application icon from launcher (AIR For Android)?

Tags: android, flash, air

How to remove application icon from launcher like this -> http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher

My application was developed by flash to make AIR Application for Android

I tried to define it in `myApp-app.xml`

```
<android>
<manifestAdditions>
<![CDATA[
<manifest>
<application>
<activity>
</activity>
</application> 
</manifest>
]]>
</manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

But it did not work.
It said `Parse error, There is a problem parsing the package.`

Answer (score 3):

Just dont give `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` to your activity in its `intent-filter`, and it will not show icon in launcher

Answer (score 1):

Open the file called AndroidManifest and find the line posted by Waqas in the previous Answer, and remove that line, then save and build the project again, you should now be able to install it (remove any old installation first) without getting the icon showing up in the launcher.

Comment: There has no this file in AIR for Android(Flash) development

Comment: Will install and try the AIR development environment myself to see how it works. Will get back in a while with what I find :)

Comment: OK, Now I can solve my problem by using apktool to decrypt appmanifest then rebuild it :D

Comment: You could fix this by opening the .apk file that you get out of AIR (with winzip or a similar tool) and change the line in the AndroidManifest.xml. And the sign and zip-align the apk file again. For more info on signing and zip-aligning look here : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Ooh, didn't see your last comment, but yes, that's one way to solve it, perhaps the only depending on how flexible the build step of AIR is.